# How to have a lambda max(a,b) function in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Is there a way, using ClickHouse's lambdas, to perform a max function over two integers ?
Like so:

```
SELECT 
    [0,1,2,3,4,5] as five, 
    arrayMap(i -> max(five[i], 3), arrayEnumerate(five)) as X
```

Returns

```
     five        expected X   
0,1,2,3,4,5     3,3,3,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I understand your example (it is not syntactically correct), but for max over two integers ClickHouse has function greatest(x,y):

```
SELECT 
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] AS five, 
  arrayMap(i -> greatest(i, 3), five) AS X

┌─five──────────┬─X─────────────┐
│ [0,1,2,3,4,5] │ [3,3,3,3,4,5] │
└───────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. I missed it in the doc. Thanks.